# Divergence of $\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\sin^{2}x}{x^{2}}dx$

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

Does $\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\sin^{2}x}{x^{2}}dx$ diverge or converge?

[Symbolab](https://www.symbolab.com/solver/definite-integral-calculator/%5Cint_%7B0%7D%5E%7B1%7D%20%5Cfrac%7B%5Cleft(sin%5E%7B2%7D%5Cleft(x%5Cright)%5Cright)%7D%7Bx%5E%7B2%7D%7Ddx) says it diverges, and I get why, but I don't get the logic behind this because you can clearly see that the graph is bounded and continuous (also $\underset{x\to0^{+}}{\lim}\frac{\sin^{2}x}{x^{2}}=1$). [Wolfram](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate%20from%200%20to%201%2C%20sin%5E2%28x%29%20%2F%20x%5E2) gives a definite answer with $Si(2)$, what is $Si(2)$?

Comment: It is convergent.

Comment: Is Symbolab wrong then?

Comment: Yes, these packages are not perfect.

Comment: @Parasect: Apparently it is wrong. Writing an integral as a difference of two divergent integrals does not prove anything.

Comment: The function $x \mapsto \sin^2 (x) / x^2 $ can be extended by continuity at $x=0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct that the integral exists because the function can be continuously extended to the closed interval $[0, 1]$.

Symbolab writes the integral as the difference of two divergent integrals
$$
\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\sin^{2}x}{x^{2}}\, dx = \int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{x^{2}}\, dx - \int_{0}^{1}\frac{\cos^{2}x}{x^{2}}\, dx
$$
but of course nothing can be concluded from that.

You can compute the integral with integration by parts:
$$
 \int_{0}^{1}\frac{\sin^{2}x}{x^{2}}\, dx = \Bigl[ -\frac 1x \sin^2(x) \Bigr]_{x=0}^{x=1} + \int_0^1 \frac{2 \sin(x)\cos(x)}{x} \, dx \\
= -\sin^2(1) + \int_0^1 \frac{\sin(2x)}{x} \, dx
= -\sin^2(1) + \int_0^2 \frac{\sin(t)}{t} \, dt \\
= \operatorname{Si}(2) - \sin^2(1)
$$
where
$$
\operatorname{Si}(x) = \int_0^x \frac{\sin(t)}{t} \, dt
$$
is the [sine integral function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_integral#Sine_integral).

Answer (score 1):

We have $\frac{\sin^2x}{x^2}\le1\forall \ 0\le x\le1$, which implies that the integral of $\frac{\sin^2x}{x^2}$ from $0$ to $1$ is bounded by $1$.

In response to @Alex 's comment, consider $g(x)=\sin x-x$. We have $g(0)=0$ and $g'(x)\le0\implies \sin x-x\le0\forall x\in\mathbb{R}$ from which the above follows.

Comment: $f(x) \leq 1$ is not obvious and doesn't follow from the limit at $x=0$

Comment: @Alex: I would consider $|\sin(x)| \le |x|$ a “well-known estimate” :)

Comment: @MartinR maybe it is. It doesn't follow from the limit anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way:

Since $\lim_{x \to 0^{+}} f(x) = 1$ and $f$ is continuous on $(0,1]$, so $f$ is continuous on $[0,1]$. If you take the derivative:
$$
f'(x) = \sin 2x -2 x f(x)
$$
which is also continuous on $(0,1]$ and 
$$
\lim_{x \to 0^{+}}f'(x) = 0
$$
so $f'(x)$ is continuous on $[0,1]$. This means $f(x)$ is uniformly continuous on $[0,1]$. Therefore $f$ is Riemann integrable:
$$
\int_{[0,1]}f < \infty
$$

Comment: If $f$ is continuous then it is Riemann integrable on $[0, 1]$, you don't need uniform continuity for that conclusion. – Actually *all* functions which are continuous on a compact interval are also uniformly continuous, even if they are not differentiable.

Comment: Isee what you mean. I used the definition of Riemann integrability from here: http://math.caltech.edu/~nets/lecture15.pdf

Comment: From that lecture notes: *“However if all we want is a qualitative result: ... all this information about the derivative is overkill.”* and *“What we get from this is that every continuous function on a closed interval is Riemann integrable on the interval”*

Comment: I think it's because I couldn't find $g(x)$ on the interval s.t. $f(x) < g(x), \ \int g(x) < \infty$. Continuity was easier to prove, and I just decided to go ahead with uniform continuity as well.

Comment: @MartinR BTW is it a typo at the end of the theorem after that: 'continuous on [a, b]/' - this slash?